# Azure MariaDB - DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ``; /*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `` */;

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm running into an error when trying to restore a backup of MariaDB

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 1488: Can't create table `pactbroker`.`latest_tagged_pact_consumer_version_orders` (errno: 1 "Operation not permitted")
```

when I'm looking at the 1488 line I see

```
1484 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `latest_tagged_pact_consumer_version_orders`;
1485 /*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `latest_tagged_pact_consumer_version_orders`*/;
1486 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
1487 SET character_set_client = utf8;
1488 /*!50001 CREATE TABLE `latest_tagged_pact_consumer_version_orders` (
1489   `provider_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
1490   `consumer_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
1491   `tag_name` tinyint NOT NULL,
1492   `latest_consumer_version_order` tinyint NOT NULL
1493 ) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
1494 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

To be honest, didn't get what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the /*!50001 ... */ syntax is called EXECUTABLE COMMENT.
the 5 digits number is the MariaDB version.
In your case, it means that if MariaDB version is 5.0.0.0.1 then the code between /* and */ will be executed otherwise not.

I'm surprised to see the DROP VIEW statement after the related DROP TABLE statement, when it should be before the DROP TABLE (you cannot DROP a VIEW on TABLE which doesn't exists anymore), or absent as the DROP VIEW is not needed anymore because the DROP TABLE drops the associated VIEWS.

Assuming, that before version 5.0.0.0.1 the DROP TABLE was not dropping the associated views (otherwise, why having an EXECUTABLE COMMENT, dropping the view if MariaDB is 5.0.0.0.1), then the DROP VIEW statement should be executed before the DROP TABLE.

Assuming you are running MariaDB 5.0.0.0.1 (not supported anymore), it would mean the view is not dropped, because the DROP VIEW statement is misplaced.

Despite, my surprise, the error code you're getting is related to a foreign key constraint issue, which may come from a bug in 5.0.0.0.1 version when you drop a table with existing view, and then recreate the table when the view has not been dropped.

I'm doing a lot of assumptions because 5.0.0.0.1 has been deployed before 2009, and even I'm "young" enough to have worked with this version, my memory has not correctly indexed the detailed and exact behavior of the DROP TABLE statement applied to views.

I will be curious to know what happens in the lines before 1484 and after 1494 and get the detailed errorlog content, allowing me to move forward from assumptions to certitudes.

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Thierry. I'm trying to restore database in Azure MariaDB managed instance which has 10.3.23 version. So commented part will not be executed. Also I've temporary disabled foreign key checks by running SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; before restoring the data.

Comment: Hello Arthas, this is weird, because if the commented parts are not executed, then why the commented create table at line 1488 is generating an error ?

Comment: Can you try to modify line 1488 :
1. like this : CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ...
2. like this : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...

Comment: Hi Thierry. My problem was in importing views not tables. The user which I created had no permissions to import those. Theoretically, it is possible to add "super" access to the user and import the views, but I had no permission to do so. My solution was to restore a backup into a new DB (as Azure MariaDB keeps a minimum of 7 days of backups which allows to go back at some point of time during these days). Then I created a folder backup of my DB. This creates an SQL file for each table. After importing tables, I've run my program which created the views automatically.